# Как закрыть адрес события в стороннем процессе

Tags: python

Не знаю как более точно и правильно сформулировать заголовок, поэтому опишу вопрос максимально подробно ниже.

Есть событие в процессе, которое создаётся при запуске приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И необходимо его закрыть/убить зная его адрес:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это сделать используя python? Если да, то куда копать и как в дальнейшем можно найти конкретный адрес, зная только имя этого события?

Comment: А что вы вдруг Python для подобного решили использовать? Не буду утверждать, что нельзя, но С или ассемблер как-то более для этого подходящими выглядят по предназначению...

Comment: @Сергей. слышал что через python можно взаимодействовать с памятью стороннего процесса и для простого скрипта не хотелось бы использовать другой яп